# Powershell Output to a share

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script, which will test a path on multiple servers and the result should be stored in a text file on a share drive.

My problem is, that when starting the remote to the target servers, they can't access the text file.

When logged onto the server with the same credentials, the script works fine.

The error message is:

> Access is denied + CategoryInfo: PermissionDenied: (\\server\folder\result\result.txt:String) [Add-Content],
>   UnauthorizedAccessException

The script itself:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
    $Location = "\\server\folder\result\result.txt"
    $path = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\*\StartUpTool.exe" -Recurse -Force | %{$_.FullName}
    $serv = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    Out-File -FilePath $Location -Encoding unicode -InputObject $serv -Append
    Add-Content -Path $Location -Value  $path -Encoding Unicode
}
```

Comment: Likely a double hop issue, see Scenario B: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2017/04/12/powershell-remoting-and-kerberos-double-hop-old-problem-new-secure-solution/

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have a better understanding now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know you can access the share on the computer executing Invoke-Command, this is a work-around:

```
$output = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
  [pscustomobject]@{
    path = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files\*\StartUpTool.exe' -Recurse -Force | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName})
    serv = $env:COMPUTERNAME
  }
}

$Location = '\\server\folder\result\result.txt'
Out-File -FilePath $Location -Encoding Unicode -InputObject $output.serv -Append
Add-Content -Path $Location -Value $output.path -Encoding Unicode
```

Basically all we are doing is outputting an object to $output from the remote server, containing all the info you were collecting. Then, we write to the share using said object.

It's hard to say if this will work exactly how you want it to - but you will need to approach the problem in this manner to bypass double-hop issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the example, this solved my issue, works like a charm!